# How do I make my title stick to the top, while the other contents go under the title and doesn't interfere with it

Tags: html, css

this is my code right now

```
#h1{
    font-family: 'open-sans';
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    left: 850px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

nothing works im in agony also tried using position sticky but it didnt work

Comment: it's no clear what want to achieve there. pls add screenshots of result and required functinality

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `position: absolute;` and only `position: fixed;` should remain.

```
h1{
position: fixed;
font-family: 'open-sans';
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: black;
top: 0;}
```

Hope that helps.
And you can also use `background-color` to make it look right.

Answer (score -1):

bro just use one position property, you are using two in the styles. Just apply three properties like:

```
.element {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width 100%
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `position:sticky` or `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp